# Error building uwsgi with pip in virtual environment

Tags: python, centos, pip, virtualenv, uwsgi

I am getting errors when I try to install uwsgi in my virtual environment in my Centos VPS. Ultimately, I cannot install uwsgi.

I am using :

```
 pip install uwsgi
```

and also :

```
pathtovirtualenv/bin/pip install uwsgi
```

I get the following output on the terminal:

```
wwwthecanonworks@thecanonworks.com [~]# ~/thecanonworks/env/bin/pip install uwsgi
Downloading/unpacking uwsgi
  Downloading uwsgi-2.0.8.tar.gz (775kB): 775kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/build/uwsgi/setup.py) egg_info for package uwsgi

Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi
    Complete output from command /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RY9JuM-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RY9JuM-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks/env/build/uwsgi
Storing debug log for failure in /home/wwwthecanonworks/.pip/pip.log
```

Here is the pip log output:

```
Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.2.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.3.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.10.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.2.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.3.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.4.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.5.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.6.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.7.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.8.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-1.4.tar.gz (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/) because it is externally hosted.
    Skipping link http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/ (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/); not a file
  Using version 2.0.8 (newest of versions: 2.0.8, 2.0.7, 2.0.6, 2.0.5.1, 2.0.5, 2.0.4, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0, 1.9.21.1, 1.9.21, 1.9.20, 1.9.19, 1.9.18.2, 1.9.18.1, 1.9.18, 1.9.17.1, 1.9.17, 1.9.16, 1.9.15, 1.9.14, 1.9.13, 1.9.12, 1$
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/u/uWSGI/uwsgi-2.0.8.tar.gz#md5=356b71060aa4c1f0e888dbca03567bd5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/uwsgi/)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_wwwthecanonworks/uwsgi/setup.py) egg_info for package uwsgi
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/uWSGI.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip_build_wwwthecanonworks/uwsgi has version 2.0.8, which satisfies requirement uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi
    Running command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_wwwthecanonworks/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exe$
    running install
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_wwwthecanonworks/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), _$
    running install

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_wwwthecanonworks...
Command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_wwwthecanonworks/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" instal$
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))

InstallationError: Command /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks2/thecanonworks/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks2/thecanonworks/env/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lmaN7I-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks2/thecanonworks/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/wwwthecanonworks/thecanonworks2/thecanonworks/env/build/uwsgi
```

here is my virtualenv bin directory :

```
wwwthecanonworks@thecanonworks.com [~/thecanonworks/env]# ls
./  ../  bin/  include/  lib/
wwwthecanonworks@thecanonworks.com [~/thecanonworks/env]# cd bin
wwwthecanonworks@thecanonworks.com [~/thecanonworks/env/bin]# ls
./  ../  activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  activate_this.py  easy_install*  easy_install-2.7*  pip*  pip2*  pip2.7*  python@  python2@  python2.7*
```

update:

I have tried a number of different things and still can't get uwsgi installed.

Comment: It seems like the `InstallationError` is cut off. Can you post the entire text?

Comment: got the rest of the installation error and posted it

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the following packages before installing uwsgi:

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 6.4 I had to install dev tools first:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```