# Install uwsgi on CENTOS 6 VPS fails with error

Tags: python, linux, installation, centos, uwsgi

Just got a shiny new VPS with CENTOS 6, so I can start migrating my sites to it.
Just installed Python 3.6 on it, with

```
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

This installed pip along with it. So can install uwsgi (was trying at first in a virtualenv but lets just keep this simple now)

```
pip install uwsgi
```

This fails with the following:

```
Installing collected packages: uWSGI
  Running setup.py install for uWSGI ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-gl88dxy5-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6q8mw4hv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include', '/usr/include']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 24
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.15\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="15" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_LIBXML2 -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    [thread 0][gcc -pthread] core/utils.o
    [thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/protocol.o
    [thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/socket.o
    [thread 4][gcc -pthread] core/logging.o
    [thread 5][gcc -pthread] core/master.o
    [thread 6][gcc -pthread] core/master_utils.o
    [thread 7][gcc -pthread] core/emperor.o
    [thread 8][gcc -pthread] core/notify.o
    [thread 9][gcc -pthread] core/mule.o
    [thread 12][gcc -pthread] core/subscription.o
    [thread 14][gcc -pthread] core/stats.o
    [thread 13][gcc -pthread] core/sendfile.o
    [thread 10][gcc -pthread] core/async.o

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-gl88dxy5-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-6q8mw4hv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-gl88dxy5-build/
```

My first response was to try and compile it from source, but that seems to fail at the same point as well.  So not sure what I can do at this point? Any suggestions?

EDIT: just tried python 3.5, and same problem.

EDIT: I don't think it is a duplicate, the suggested solutions are either to install the dev tools (already done to compile Python), use the package manager (not available) or compile from source (just said that also fails).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error building uwsgi with pip in virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26876251/608639) and [Error in installing uwsgi on ubuntu with python 3.5 using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42547502/608639).

Comment: The questions pointed to offer no solution that works.  I specifically said I also tried to compile from source and that fails as well.